# Error - ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a code to make a simple tic tac toe in python but an error is continuously popping. I can't figure out the problem.. pls help[image]

[image]
The code works fine in first case but I don't know why it isn't

You may check the code on any editor -

```py
    import random
    from random import choices
    board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    weights = [0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.3, 0.05 , 0.1, 0.05, 0.1]
    _board = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9]
    
    def choose_random():
        return(choices(board,weights))
    
    def draw():
        print(_board[0], _board[1], _board[2])
        print(_board[3], _board[4], _board[5])
        print(_board[6], _board[7], _board[8])
    
    def user_chance():
        draw()
        choice = int(input('Choose any of the block: '))
        board.remove(choice)
        index = _board.index(choice)
        _board[index] = "X"
        comp_chance()    
    
    def comp_chance():
        if(len(board) == 0):
            print("It's a tie !")
        else:
            random = choose_random()
            board.remove(random)
            index = _board.index(random)
            _board[index] = 'O'
            user_chance()
        
    user_chance()
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question
http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues that you need to address here:

- You are removing the value from `board` list and not from the `weights` list, so you are getting this problem
- `choose_random()` is returning a list of `k` values, you haven't specified `k` so it will return a list of with one value. You should add `[0]` at the end of return statement.
- You should also add check for whether user have entered valid position on the board or not, otherwise, you will get error that `value is not in list`

  ```
  from random import choices
  board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  weights = [0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.3, 0.05 , 0.1, 0.05, 0.1]
  _board = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9]

  def choose_random():
      return(choices(board,weights))[0]

  def draw():
      print(_board[0], _board[1], _board[2])
      print(_board[3], _board[4], _board[5])
      print(_board[6], _board[7], _board[8])

  def user_chance():
      draw()
      choice = int(input('Choose any of the block: '))
      board.remove(choice)
      index = _board.index(choice)
      del weights[index]
      _board[index] = "X"
      comp_chance()    

  def comp_chance():
      if(len(board) == 0):
          print("It's a tie !")
      else:
          random = choose_random()
          board.remove(random)
          index = _board.index(random)
          del weights[index]
          _board[index] = 'O'
          user_chance()

  user_chance()
  ```

Comment: This produces IndexError: list assignment index out of range - using a dictionary for the weights instead of a list is better because the length of the list will be always changing. Later in the game, the list will be shorter and it falls apart.

Comment: I'm not the op.

Comment: No problem dude ! Even your trials help me learn a lot..

Answer (score 2):

In line 17 you are removing "choice" from board list, when you call choose_random() lengths of board list and weights list do not match, so you are getting error .

Answer (score 1):

I commented the changes I made:

```py
import random
from random import choices
board = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] #Changed to strings
weight_values = {"1": 0.1,
                 "2": 0.05,
                 "3": 0.1,
                 "4": 0.05,
                 "5": 0.3,
                 "6": 0.05,
                 "7": 0.1,
                 "8": 0.05,
                 "9": 0.1} #Now a dictionary
_board = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9]

def choose_random():
    return(choices(board,list(weight_values.values()))) #weight_values.values() returns a list of the weights, which is needed for this function

def draw():
    print(_board[0], _board[1], _board[2])
    print(_board[3], _board[4], _board[5])
    print(_board[6], _board[7], _board[8])

def user_chance():
    draw()
    
    choice = (input('Choose any of the block: '))
    
    board.remove(choice) #Remove from board[]
    del weight_values[choice] #Remove from weight_values{}
    
    index = _board.index(int(choice))
    _board[index] = "X"
    comp_chance()    

def comp_chance():
    if(len(board) == 0):
        print("It's a tie !")
    else:
        random = choose_random()

        board.remove(str(random[0]))  #Remove from board[]    
        index = _board.index(int(random[0]))
        
        del weight_values[str(random[0])] #Remove from weight_values{}
        _board[index] = 'O'
        user_chance()
    
user_chance()
```

The player can still choose an already marked square, so that will need fixing. The problem was you weren't removing the weight values as you removed the board values. The amount of weight values and board values has to be the same. As a dictionary, it is much easier to manage.