# What does ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population mean?

Tags: python, random, python-imaging-library, valueerror

I'm trying to make an art combiner that gets different images and combines them to give a unique image.

But I get an error when I added weights.
ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population

I'm using random.choices

I first get the path of the images

```
# importing Libaris
from typing import final
from PIL import Image
from random import choices

img_num = 10
img_made =  1

backgrounds=[
r"./NFT Duck/Backgrounds/blue.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Backgrounds/brown.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Backgrounds/Green.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Backgrounds/Purble.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Backgrounds/Sunset.png"
]

ducks=[
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-Gray.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-Green.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-Brown.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-Rainbow.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-White.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Ducks/Duck-Yellow.png"
]

hats=[
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Cap-Backwords.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Cap-Black.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Hat-Dark.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Hat-Light.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Hat-White.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Hats/Top-Hat-Black.png"
]

eyes=[
r"./NFT Duck/Eyes/Black-eyes.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Eyes/Cyen-Eyes.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Eyes/Future-eyes.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Eyes/Pink-eyes.png"
r"./NFT Duck/Eyes/Red-Eyes.png"
]

cigar=[
r"./NFT Duck/cigars/Cigret.png"
r"./NFT Duck/cigars/None.png"
]
```

Then I choose a random image in a for loop, it worked until I added weights.

the for loop

```
for i in range(img_num):

# Varebals
r_bg = choices(backgrounds, weights=(25,23,24,25,3))[0]
r_duck = choices(ducks, weights=(7,16,26,1,25,25))[0]
r_hat = choices(hats, weights=(15,25,29,28,2,1))[0]
r_eye = choices(eyes, weights=(96,1,.5,1,2))[0]
r_cigare = choices(cigar,weights=(.5,99.5))[0]

bg = Image.open(r_bg)
duck = Image.open(r_duck)
hat = Image.open(r_hat)
eye = Image.open(r_eye)
cigar = Image.open(r_cigare)

# Drawing the image and saving
start = Image.alpha_composite(bg, duck)
intermediate = Image.alpha_composite(start, hat)
semi_final = Image.alpha_composite(intermediate,eye)
final = Image.alpha_composite(semi_final, cigar)
final.save(f"./Final/Duck #{img_made}.png", "PNG")

img_made += 1
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64510657/error-valueerror-the-number-of-weights-does-not-match-the-population-in-pytho)

Comment: Your amount of cigare images is not matching the weights given.